# How can I get iTerm to open a group of windows when it's started?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

Apple's Terminal app allows you to save a Windows Group. It seems like iTerm probably has a similar sort of function, but I can't figure how to do it.  Right now, it opens one window which is the wrong size, and wrong location.

Answer (score 3):

You want to look at the "Bookmarks" feature.

- Open the bookmarks interface (Menu Bookmarks -> Manage Bookmarks).
- Click the new folder button (red + on a blue folder).
- Select the new folder and click the add button (+).
- Edit the bookmark name, command, profile settings etc as desired.

Launch the bookmarks from the menu.

To launch a bookmark as the default, select the bookmark and check button "Set as default" in the middle of the bottom toolbar on the manage bookmark pane. This seems only to work on a toplevel bookmark, not a sub-level item.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to get a certain bookmark group to load on startup?

Answer (score 1):

I opened a feature request for you in iTerm2. Star [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=311) to be notified when it changes.